# What is the point of entering an email during `npm adduser`?

Tags: npm

When I try to retrieve my authentication token for npm via `npm adduser` or `npm login`, I'm asked to provide my email address with the note "this is public".

It doesn't matter what I enter here, as long as `npm` believes it's an email address.

The address is not stored in `.npmrc` and it's obvisouly not validated against the backend in any way.

So, what is the point?